# Hibernate CreateCriteria for dependent class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am working on an application where I have to display data/information about the vehicle details. I have 2 tables `make` and `model` with `make_id` being the foreign key in `model` table. I have 2 entity classes `Make` and `Model` as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "make")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="make_id")
public class Make {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "make_id")
    private String makeId;

    @Column(name = "make_name")
    private String makeName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mfg_unit_id")
    private MfgUnit mfgUnit;

    // Getter and Setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "model")
public class Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private String modelId;

    @Column(name = "model_creation_date")
    private Date modelCreationDate;

    @Column(name = "make_id")
    private long makeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "make_id")
    private Make make;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

I am able to retrieve all the `Make`s, but my requirement is to only retrieve the `Make`s for which the `model_creation_date` is between today and last 30 days. Can anyone help me with how to build the Hibernate criteria for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be another solution, but to achieve this you need to modify your Make class as following introducing a new relationship (@OneToMany) with Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "make")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="make_id")
public class Make {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "make_id")
    private String makeId;

    @Column(name = "make_name")
    private String makeName;

    // ** introduced new relationship **
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="make", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Model> models;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mfg_unit_id")
    private MfgUnit mfgUnit;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

And keep the 'Model' class as it is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "model")
public class Model {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private String modelId;

    // change the datatype as Date or similar Datatype
    @Column(name = "model_creation_date")
    private Date modelCreationDate;

    @Column(name = "make_id")
    private long makeId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "make_id")
    private Make make;

    // Getter and Setters
}
```

Once you have the relationship with 'Model' from 'Make' you can execute the following code to get your result:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// today 
Date toDate=cal.getTime(); 
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, -30 );
//date before 30 days
Date fromDate=cal.getTime();


Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Make.class , "m")
        .createAlias("models", "s")
        .add(Restrictions.between("s.modelCreationDate",  fromDate, toDate))
        // if the above condition dosen't give you exact result you may try following(2)
        // try gt or lt ... as needed 
        //.add(Restrictions.ge("publicationDate", fromDate)) 
        //.add(Restrictions.le("publicationDate", fromDate))
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

List<Make> ll2 = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have no idea why did you declare  date as String:

private **String** modelCreationDate;

Anyway, I assume you will declare modelCreationDate as Date/LocalDate or with similar Type. I haven't tested the code but I hope the following code will resolve your issue. Good luck!

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// today 
Date toDate=cal.getTime(); 
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, -30 );
//date before 30 days
Date fromDate=cal.getTime();


Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Model.class , "s")
        .createAlias("make", "m")
        .add(Restrictions.between("s.modelCreationDate",  fromDate, toDate))
        // if the above condition dosen't give you exact result you may try following(2)
        // try gt or lt ... as needed 
        //.add(Restrictions.ge("publicationDate", fromDate)) 
        //.add(Restrictions.le("publicationDate", fromDate))
        .setProjection(
                Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("m.makeId").as("makeId"))
                .add(Projections.property("m.makeName").as("makeName")) 
            )
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Make.class));


List<Make> ll2 = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Hi @user3169715, Thank you for your response. I have multiple @ManyToOne joins in the `Make` class also. I have just listed a couple of the properties in my question. I have now edited my question to show an example for other @ManyToOne column too. So, is there a way to achieve this without using projections and selecting individual columns as I want all of the details populated automatically like Hibernate does by default?

Comment: hi @Prasann, have a look in the following answer.

Comment: Hi @user3169715, was there a link you wanted to post? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to [user3169715's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54588926/1036310), I could also retrieve the records using a query

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date toDate = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
Date fromDate = cal.getTime();

String hql = "SELECT make FROM Model m where m.modelCreationDate between :from_date and :to_date";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("from_date", fromDate);
query.setParameter("to_date", toDate);

List results = query.list(); // Result list
```